# Decoupling the loading of data, sorting and usage

Tags: design

I have the following requirements:

1. Load data from a variety of sources and fill a list with it
2. Use a batch of data to perform some computation

Some additional information:

1. The algorithm for computation expects the list of data to be ordered by a key that comes with the data.
2. I want to use a queue instead of a list inside the algorithm for performance reasons (Loaded data is already stored sorted)
3. The data batch needs to be loaded beforehand

I tried to break the requirements up into different classes and came up with this design (pseudocode):

```
class Data {
    int key;
    // some more data fields
}

class SortedDataQueue{
    Data peek();
    Data dequeue();
    void enqueue(Data);
}

class ComputesData {
    Result performComputation();
    void setDataBatch(SortedDataQueue dataBatch);
}

class DataLoader {
    static SortedDataQueue loadFromJsonFile(File file);
    static SortedDataQueue loadFromDB(DataDAO dao);
}
```

Is this a good design?

I try to get better at software architecture/design, but it is really hard without someone experienced to review your work. I tried to follow the SOLID principles in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've done a great job in decoupling the dependencies, what I could suggest here is to not return already `SortedDataQueue` object from `DataLoader`  since it's responsibility is only to retrieve data.
In that case, you can create the class:

```
    class DataCollector {
        SortedDataQueue collectIntoQueue();
        DataCollector init(Array<Data> dataArray);
    }
```

And `DataCollector`'s responsobility is to collect your batch of data into queue.

Comment: I thought the same when i refined my implementation yesterday. I will probably return an Array<Data> from my DataLoader and use a SortedDataQueue in my ComputesData class. If i ever get into a situation where i get unsorted data i can then quite easily implement a class that sorts the Array and returns a SortedDataQueue that i can work with.